# How to set the property for each "subUIBezierPath"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

**Problem description**

I'm trying to add a "**gesture unlock**" function in my app but I have a problem as shown in the attached image. I found some unnecessary lines also draw out. In fact, I just need to show out the line to connect each "buttons".

Please check the image below

[image: -> Image click here <-]

Below is my Code under `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`

```
    // Main Path
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    // Rect path
    UIBezierPath *rectPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
    [path appendPath:rectPath];

    // 9 circle path
    [self.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PPSingleCircle * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:obj.frame];
        [path appendPath:circlePath];

    }];

    // clip the path
    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
    [path addClip];

    // add line to each select Views
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.selectViews count]; i++) {
        PPSingleCircle *singleView = self.selectViews[i];

        if (i == 0) {
            [path moveToPoint:singleView.center];
        }else {
            [path addLineToPoint:singleView.center];
        }
    }

    // add line to current point
    [path addLineToPoint:self.currentPoint];

    // set display style
    [kLineColor setStroke];
    path.lineWidth = kLineWidth;
    path.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;
    path.lineCapStyle  = kCGLineCapRound;
    [path stroke];
```

Comment: You will need to make the connecting line path as a separate bezier path.  In your code, you are having a single path that contains the circles and also the paths between them..

Comment: @Shripada yes, i have make to new path to store the connecting line and set the "lineWidth" = 10, and then i append this "new path" on may "main path", after stroke i found the line width also is 1 not 10.

Comment: @Shripada yup, i get you meaning now, it fixed my issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I fix the issue as below

```
// Main Path
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

// Line Path
UIBezierPath *linePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

// Rect path
UIBezierPath *rectPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
[path appendPath:rectPath];

// 9 circle path
[self.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PPSingleCircle * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:obj.frame];
    [path appendPath:circlePath];
}];

// clip the path
path.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
[path addClip];
// stroke the "Main path" first
[path stroke];

// add line to each select Views
for (int i = 0; i < [self.selectViews count]; i++) {

    PPSingleCircle *singleView = self.selectViews[i];
    if (i == 0) {
        [linePath moveToPoint:singleView.center];
    }else {
        [linePath addLineToPoint:singleView.center];
    }
}

// add line to current point
PPSingleCircle *view = self.selectViews[0];
if (view.status != CircleStatusError) {
    [linePath addLineToPoint:self.currentPoint];
}

// set display style
[kLineColor setStroke];
linePath.lineWidth = kLineWidth;
linePath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;
linePath.lineCapStyle  = kCGLineCapRound;

// add line path and draw
[linePath stroke];
```